# Is running WordFence and Akismet on a wordpress install overkill?

Tags: wordpress

On an up-to-date wordpress instance, is running both [Akismet](https://akismet.com/) and [Wordfence](https://www.wordfence.com/) overkill? That is, do they overlap? Is there a performance hit by running both?

Answer (score 1):

Akismet helps to reduce link spam from commenters. Wordfence is a software firewall, similar to anti-maleware. They can be used simultaneously. Though, if you disable comments, you don't need Akimset.